# Does EventViewer have a process I can run directly?

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer

I'm working on foreign language test system and I struggle to find standard Windows Utilities like Event Viewer as they have different names.

Does the Windows Event Viewer have a .exe I can run directly, if so where and what is it?

Comment: It does but the name is localized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can directly run "Event Viewer" using **`eventvwr.msc`**. But it does not have a dedicated .exe file – it is actually a *document* to be opened by the Microsoft Management Console (MMC).

The actual image name for Microsoft Management Console is `mmc.exe`, but if you start it directly you will just get an empty console with no tools.

(However, you can use mmc.exe to build your own toolset using *File → Add/Remove Snap-Ins* and save it as a custom .msc file – you can have EventVwr, DevMgmt, DiskMgmt, and a bunch of other tools all in one place.)

Many other Windows administrative tools are also Management Console documents located at `%SystemRoot%\System32\*.msc` – e.g. Device Manager is devmgmt.msc, Active Directory Users is dsa.msc, and so on.